# PHP Lua registration system

Tags: php, mysql, lua, phpmyadmin, coronasdk

I am stuck here with this problem all day and all other options I have in mind are long gone . I created a login and registration system for my social network app . I stopped working on the app for a couple of months maybe and now I keep on getting an error . The problem is on the registration page .

I put in all the credentials and then hit the registration button and it tells me `Error signing up` and at the same time it prints out the statement that tells me the registration was successful from the PHP side `Successful` . The credentials go into the database though . And I can log in with them . But at the registration page when the registration is successful, I'm suppose to go to the login page to log in . Please help me .

signup.php:

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "hashx10h_brandon", "bigman23", "hashx10h_hash");

            if(isset($_POST['Register'])) {

               if (empty($_POST["username"])) {
                echo"Fill in username to sign up";
                } else {

                if (empty($_POST["pw"])) {
                 echo"Fill in password to sign up";
                } else {

                if (empty($_POST["pw2"])) {
                echo"Confirm password to sign up";
                 } else {

                if (empty($_POST["email"])) {
                     echo"Fill in email to sign up";
                 } else {

                if ($_POST['pw'] == $_POST['pw2']) {
                 $username = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["username"]);
                 $pw= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pw"]);
         $pw2= mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["pw2"]);
                 $email = mysqli_real_escape_string($con, $_POST["email"]);

                 $result = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='" . $username . "'");

                    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0)
                    {
                    echo "Username exists . <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br /> ";
                    } else {

                       $result2 = mysqli_query($con ,"SELECT * FROM users WHERE email='" . $email. "'");

                       if(mysqli_num_rows($result2) > 0)
                       {
                       echo "Email exist.  <a href= index.php>Try again</a><br /> ";
                       } else {

                       $pw = password_hash($pw, PASSWORD_BCRYPT, array('cost' => 14));          

               $sql = "INSERT INTO users (username, pw, email) VALUES('" . $username . "', '" . $pw . "', '" . $email . "')";

                       if(mysqli_query($con, $sql)){                                  
                       // if insert checked as successful echo username and password saved successfully
            echo"successful ."; 
                       }else{
                       echo mysqli_error($con);
                       }   

                    } } } else{
               echo "The passwords do not match.";  // and send them back to registration page
            }
}
}}}}
```

Register.lua:

```
local widget = require("widget")
-- forward declare the text fields
local json = require("json")

local username
local pw
local email 

local function urlencode(str)
if (str) then
str = string.gsub (str, "\n", "\r\n")
str = string.gsub (str, "([^%w ])",
    function (c) return string.format ("%%%02X", string.byte(c)) end)
str = string.gsub (str, " ", "+")
end
return str    
end

local function passwordMatch( event )
if ( pw.text ~= pw2.text ) then

    local alert = native.showAlert( "Error", "Passwords do not match .", { "Try again" }  )

    return true 

    else
      return false
end
end

local function networkListener( event )

if ( event.isError ) then
      local alert = native.showAlert( "Network Error . Check Connection", "Connect to Internet", { "Try again" }  )
else
    if event.response == "success" then
        -- put the code here to go to where the user needs to be
        -- after a successful registration
        composer.gotoScene("login")

    else
        -- put code here to notify the user of the problem, perhaps
        -- a native.alert() dialog that shows them the value of event.response
        -- and take them back to the registration screen to let them try again
      local json = require("json")
      json.prettify( event )
      local alert = native.showAlert( "Error Signing Up", event.response, { "Try again" }  )

end
end
end

local function userRegister( event )
if ( "ended" == event.phase ) then

    if passwordMatch() == true then 

    else

    local parameters = {}
    parameters.body = "Register=1&username=" .. username.text .. "&pw=" .. pw.text .. "&pw2=" .. pw2.text .. "&email=" .. urlencode( email.text ) 
    local URL = "http://hash.x10host.com/cgi-bin/hash/signup.php"
    network.request(URL, "POST", networkListener, parameters)

 end
 end
 end

 username = native.newTextField( 160, 160, 180, 30 )  -- take the local off since it's forward declared
 username.placeholder = "Username"
 screenGroup:insert(username)

 pw = native.newTextField( 160, 205,180, 30 ) -- take the local off since it's forward declared
 pw.isSecure = true
   pw.placeholder = "Password"
  screenGroup:insert(pw)

  pw2 = native.newTextField( 160, 250,180, 30 ) -- take the local off since it's forward declared
  pw2.isSecure = true
  pw2.placeholder = "Confirm Password"
  screenGroup:insert(pw2)

  email = native.newTextField( 160, 290, 180, 30 ) -- take the local off since it's forward declared
  email.placeholder = "E-mail"
  screenGroup:insert(email)
```

Any help ?!?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to replace line

`echo"successful .";`

with

`echo "success";`

in signup.php. Response from php scipt will be stored in `event.response` so when you compare both string they match.

**Note**: Instruction `json.prettify( event )` returns a `string`. To ouput it to console use `print` function.

Comment: Yeah I already fixed it last night but this is the right answer so i'll accept it